# SSL error in certificates for python self-signed aws lambda

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssl, aws-lambda, python-requests

I was trying to invoke a web-URL using self-signed certificates. But it is giving some error involving certificate failure. I am using python requests as :

```
import json
import requests as req
uri='someurl'
 headers= {'Authorization': 'Basic user:Welcome1' ,"content-type": "application/json","Accept":"application/json"}
r=req.get(uri,params=headers,verify='certificate.pem')
    print(r)
```

i have tried generating .cer file as well but it is giving the below error:

```
{
  "errorMessage": "HTTPSConnectionPool(host="host", port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: url=Basic+user%3AWelcome1&content-type=application%2Fjson&Accept=application%2Fjson (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(0, 'unknown error (_ssl.c:3517)'),))",
  "errorType": "SSLError",
  "stackTrace": [
    [
      "/var/task/lambda_function.py",
      7,
      "lambda_handler",
      "r=req.get(uri,params=headers,verify='certificate.pem')"
    ],
    [
      "/var/task/requests/api.py",
      75,
      "get",
      "return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)"
    ],
    [
      "/var/task/requests/api.py",
      60,
      "request",
      "return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)"
    ],
    [
      "/var/task/requests/sessions.py",
      524,
      "request",
      "resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)"
    ],
    [
      "/var/task/requests/sessions.py",
      637,
      "send",
      "r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)"
    ],
    [
      "/var/task/requests/adapters.py",
      514,
      "send",
      "raise SSLError(e, request=request)"
    ]
  ]
}
```

Comment: Have to tried accessing any other site using request. AWS lambda python don't include request library

Comment: I already added library. Its working from the browser, but not working from the local system.